# Git + NetBeans = файлы только для чтения

Tags: git, chmod, netbeans

Возникли затруднения у меня с гитом и нетбинсом.

Вот ход моих действий:

**На хостинге:**

1. Создание репозитория в существующем каталоге `git init`
2. Добавления всех файлов и папок `git add ...`
3. Первый коммит `git commit -m 'initial project version'`

**На локальной машине:**

1. Клонирую репозиторий по ssh: `sudo git clone ssh://user@host/path/to/project/ /local/path/to/project`
2. Создаю проект c существующим кодом в Netbeans. Все создается, Netbeans подтягивает git, возле названия проекта появляется надпись `master`.
3. Но все файлы в Netbeans доступны только для чтения. Решил данную проблему только просвоив всем файлам права 777 командой `sudo find /local/path/to/project -type f -exec chmod 777 {} +`

Это нормально, что все файлы проекта на локальной машине теперь имеют права 777? Если нет, то как это исправить?

P.S. ставил всем права 775, Netbeans уже не мог редактировать файлы.

Comment: Ну вы же сделали `sudo git clone,` так что это вполне ожидаемо. Сделайте `git clone` без `sudo` и все должно быть хорошо.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать без sudo ругается "Отказано в доступе".

Comment: @Demyan112rv

- Да, поскольку вы своей командой пытались склонировать репозиторий в папку `/local` (в корне!), что, естественно, нельзя сделать, не обладая правами суперпользователя. То есть, грубо говоря, система пыталась вас предупредить о том, что вы, скорее всего, пытаетесь сделать что-то не то, но вы заткнули ее, набрав `sudo` :)

- Попробуйте `git clone REPOSITORY_URL /usr/local/path/to/project`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Это я условно написал путь /local... У меня проекты лежат в папке /var/www/ Не знаю, плохо это или хорошо. Но без sudo я в этой папке ничего не могу делать

Comment: @Demyan112rv вы на той машине, куда клонируете разрабатывать будете или локальный деплой делать? Из /var/www принято пользователю `www-data` давать сайты раздавать, а разрабатывать принято в /home/<username>/[source|src|projects|итп] своим пользователем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Если я правильно понимаю, то расположение проекта в `/var/www` продиктовано тем, что у вас есть какой-то сервис а-ля Apache, в качестве DocumentRoot для которого используется как раз `/var/www`.

> При этом вы хотите совместить возможность редактирования проекта в NetBeans с тем, чтобы Apache-подобная штука сразу же подхватывала изменения при любых операциях в репозитории git.

- У вас есть несколько вариантов решения этой задачи:
- `(1)` Сделать группу (условно, `people-who-can-touch-var-www`), добавить в нее пользователя `apache` и вашего текущего пользователя, а после этого сделать соответствующий `chown / chmod` для `/var/www`.

> [Смотрите **первый** ответ по ссылке.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)

- `(2)` В используемом вами веб-сервере настроить некоторый аналог `virtualhost` для папки с проектом в `$HOME`. Этот вариант лично мне кажется более предпочтительным, поскольку вы сможете просто редактировать проект, расположенный в вашей домашней директории, без необходимости вообще трогать права для `/var/www/`.

> [Смотрите **третий** ответ по ссылке.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www)